# How do I get sed to delete the second block of lines in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, html

I have hundreds of badly-written HTML files that have two HTML sections, like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
several header lines
</HEAD>
<BODY>
hundreds of lines of content
</BODY>
</HTML>
<HTML>
dozens of lines
</HTML>
```

I want to delete the entire second HTML section using GNU sed 4.7 on Linux. I've tried things like:

```
sed '0,/<HTML>/! /<HTML>/,/<\/HTML>/d'
```

but that doesn't work. I'd like to do something like this but it's not syntactically correct:

```
sed '/<HTML>/2,/<\/HTML>/d'
```

Help please.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the file is otherwise a well-formed XML document, you may use `xmlstarlet` to reformat the document.  Doing so with the `--recover` option would make the utility output the first top-level tag and all its contents, but would discard any other top-level tags.

Example:

```
$ xmlstarlet fo --recover --omit-decl --noindent file >newfile
file:9.1: Extra content at the end of the document
<HTML>
^
```

```
$ cat newfile
<HTML>
<HEAD>
several header lines
</HEAD>
<BODY>
hundreds of lines of content
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it the other way around: print all lines but quit on the first occurence of `</HTML>`

```
sed -ni 'p;/<\/HTML>/q' file
```

Use without `-i` to test first.

Or way simpler:

```
sed -i '/<\/HTML>/q'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as [@FelixJN's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670164/133219) but using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '{print}; /<\/HTML>/{exit}' file
<HTML>
<HEAD>
several header lines
</HEAD>
<BODY>
hundreds of lines of content
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Make it `awk -i inplace 'script' *` if you want to do "inplace" editing on all your files at once and have GNU awk.